.AddEnvironmentVariables() is empty when my Integration Tests Project call Program.cs
My Program.cs is:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddApiServices(configuration);

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseApi(app.Environment, app.Services.GetRequiredService<IApiVersionDescriptionProvider>());

app.Run();

[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage(Justification = "Program.cs will be tested with integration tests")]
[SuppressMessage("Major Code Smell", "S1118: Utility classes should not have public constructors", Justification = "Necessary for code coverage")]
public partial class Program;

This is Integration Test
public class BaseITFixture : IDisposable
{
    public readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly TestsSetupManager<BaseITFixture> _TestsSetupManager;

    public BaseITFixture()
    {
        IntegrationTestsApplicationFactory<Program> factory = new()
        {
            Options = new ConfigurationOptions
            {
                ENV = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENV") ?? "test"
            }
        };

        _client = factory.CreateClient();

        var token = TokenGenerator.GenerateToken();

        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

        _TestsSetupManager = new TestsSetupManager<BaseITFixture>(SubscribeToTestsSetupProcess(), this);
        _TestsSetupManager.InitProcess();
        _TestsSetupManager.Seed();
    }

    private bool disposedValue;
    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _TestsSetupManager.Clean();
                _client.Dispose();
            }
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(disposing: true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private static Func<List<ITestsSetup<BaseITFixture>>> SubscribeToTestsSetupProcess()
    {
        return () =>
        {
            return [];
        };
    }

}

This is IntegrationTestsApplicationFactory class
public class IntegrationTestsApplicationFactory<TStartup> : WebApplicationFactory<TStartup> where TStartup : class
{
    public ConfigurationOptions Options { get; set; } = new ConfigurationOptions();

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
        {
            builder.AddIntegrationTestsConfiguration(Options);
        }).ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IPolicyEvaluator, FakePolicyEvaluator>();
        });
    }

    public class FakePolicyEvaluator : IPolicyEvaluator
    {
        public virtual async Task<AuthenticateResult> AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, HttpContext context)
        {
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
            principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity([new Claim("Information", "some code")], "FakeScheme"));

            return await Task.FromResult(AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal,
                new AuthenticationProperties(), "FakeScheme")));
        }

        public virtual async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy,
            AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object? resource)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success());
        }
    }
}

While debugging my tests I noticed that they fail because when external APIs are called in the flow, it fails to retrieve part of the URL written in the environment variables because they are not loaded. I know that maybe by modifying the Program file or adding the Startup.cs class it could fix it but I am strictly forbidden to modify the Program file and I cannot add the Startup.cs file.

How are you running the tests? Maybe the caller does not have the env vars set?

That's not the problem, ENV is set in the pipelines.... locally I launch the tests in debug, when the breakpoint arrives in the program class in the configuration there are no variables with the connection strings etc etc
